# Delphi 7 - Not Enough Actual Parameters

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm so new to Delphi 7, also in this forum and I've questions.

I have successfully converted an url string to hex using Jorlen Young's **function StrToHex** - [Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) Interface Unit v1.3](http://www.02t.cn/article/code/247.html)!.

But, when I implement his **function EncryptString**, then I got error at the very bottom of my code: **Encrypt := EncryptString('www.website.com');** with the following messsage:

```
[Hint] Unit1.pas(xx): Variable 'st' is declared but never used in 'EncryptString'
[Error] Unit1.pas(xx): Not enough actual parameters
[Fatal Error] Project1.dpr(5): Could not compile used unit 'Unit1.pas'
```

Could you give me some tips in how to implement the "Key" and "KeyBit" option into my syntax: **Encrypt := EncryptString('www.website.com');** ?

I would appreciate any help.

...here is my code :

```
    .....................
    .....................

type
  TKeyBit = (kb128, kb192, kb256);
    .....................
    .....................
    procedure IdMappedPortTCP1Execute(AThread: TIdMappedPortThread);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
{ Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

function StrToHex(Const str: Ansistring): Ansistring;
asm
    push ebx
    push esi
    push edi
    test eax,eax
    jz   @@Exit
    mov  esi,edx
    mov  edi,eax
    mov  edx,[eax-4]
    test edx,edx
    je   @@Exit      {Length(S) = 0}
    mov  ecx,edx
    Push ecx
    shl  edx,1
    mov  eax,esi
    {$IFDEF VER210}
    movzx ecx, word ptr [edi-12]
    {$ENDIF}
    call System.@LStrSetLength
    mov  eax,esi
    Call UniqueString
    Pop   ecx
  @@SetHex:
    xor  edx,edx
    mov  dl, [edi]
    mov  ebx,edx
    shr  edx,4
    mov  dl,byte ptr[edx+@@HexChar]
    mov  [eax],dl
    and  ebx,$0F
    mov  dl,byte ptr[ebx+@@HexChar]
    inc  eax
    mov  [eax],dl
    inc  edi
    inc  eax
    loop @@SetHex
  @@Exit:
    pop  edi
    pop  esi
    pop  ebx
    ret
  @@HexChar: db '0123456789ABCDEF'
end;

function EncryptString(Value: AnsiString; Key: AnsiString; KeyBit: TKeyBit = kb128): AnsiString;
var
  {$IFDEF VER210}
  SS,DS: TMemoryStream;
  {$ELSE}
  SS, DS: TStringStream;
  {$ENDIF}
  Size: Int64;
  AESKey128: TAESKey128;
  AESKey192: TAESKey192;
  AESKey256: TAESKey256;
  st: AnsiString;
begin
  Result := '';
  {$IFDEF VER210}
    ss := TMemoryStream.Create;
    SS.WriteBuffer(PAnsiChar(Value)^,Length(Value));
    DS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  {$ELSE}
    SS := TStringStream.Create(Value);
    DS := TStringStream.Create('');
  {$ENDIF}
  try
    Size := SS.Size;
    DS.WriteBuffer(Size, SizeOf(Size));
    if KeyBit = kb128 then
    begin
      FillChar(AESKey128, SizeOf(AESKey128), 0 );
      Move(PAnsiChar(Key)^, AESKey128, Min(SizeOf(AESKey128), Length(Key)));
      EncryptAESStreamECB(SS, 0, AESKey128, DS);
    end;
    if KeyBit = kb192 then
    begin
      FillChar(AESKey192, SizeOf(AESKey192), 0 );
      Move(PAnsiChar(Key)^, AESKey192, Min(SizeOf(AESKey192), Length(Key)));
      EncryptAESStreamECB(SS, 0, AESKey192, DS);
    end;
    if KeyBit = kb256 then
    begin
      FillChar(AESKey256, SizeOf(AESKey256), 0 );
      Move(PAnsiChar(Key)^, AESKey256, Min(SizeOf(AESKey256), Length(Key)));
      EncryptAESStreamECB(SS, 0, AESKey256, DS);
    end;
    {$IFDEF VER210}
      SetLength(st,Ds.Size);
      DS.Position := 0;
      DS.ReadBuffer(PAnsiChar(st)^,DS.Size);
      Result := StrToHex(st);
    {$ELSE}
      Result := StrToHex(DS.DataString);
    {$ENDIF}
  finally
    SS.Free;
    DS.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdMappedPortTCP1Execute(AThread: TIdMappedPortThread);
var Payload, Encrypt:String;
begin

Encrypt := EncryptString('www.website.com');

  if Pos('CONNECT',AThread.NetData)<>0 then
    begin
      if host.Text = 'Operator' then
        begin
           Athread.OutboundClient.Write(Athread.NetData+#13#10);
           Payload := 'GET http://'+Encrypt+'/ HTTP/1.1'+#13#10;
           Athread.NetData:= Athread.NetData+Payload;
        end;
    end;
end.
```

Cheers,
RzV

Comment: That `EncryptString` function has two required parameters. You passed just one. You need to specify the `Key` parameter value as well.

Comment: There's only one way to interpret the error message

Comment: Could you give me some examples in how to implement the **Key** parameter into my syntax: **Encrypt := EncryptString('www.website.com');** ?

Comment: You can choose a [`random number`](https://xkcd.com/221/), or anything that you want. That should be secret. But if you're asking how write that line of code, then note, that parameters that are passed to functions in Delphi are separated by commas, so e.g. `Encrypt := EncryptString('www.website.com', '4');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EncryptString has 2 required and one optional parameter. You need at least to provide the key.